# Error installing GD Toolkit

Tags: php, ubuntu, gd, apt-get, php-gd

I have been trying to install the GD toolkit on my Ubuntu VM. The operation is simple enough:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

However, when I run this, I get a 404 (Not Found error) for a package:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-gd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 38.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 163 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main php5-gd amd64 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.153 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main php5-gd amd64 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-gd_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.151 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Did you try "sudo apt-get update" before trying to install GD library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer from user1190992 apt-get was simply out of date....

This command did the trick:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Internets might be all broken. try

> $ curl 91.189.92.153

Comment: Your suggesting returns this:


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /</h1>